# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in core\cake\basics.php on line 118

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, line

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in  core\cake\basics.php on line 118  ) please some one help me.

```
}

function pluginSplit($name, $dotAppend = false, $plugin = null) {
  if (strpos( $name, '.' ) !== false) {
    $parts = explode( '.', $name, 2 );

    if ($dotAppend) {
      $parts->0 .= '.';
    }
    return $parts;
}
```

Comment: And line 118 is?  Btw, in what you show I don't see the final `}` of the function...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access the 0th element of the array, the proper syntax is `$parts[0]`.

If you're trying to access a numeric property, either wrap the number in curly braces or use a variable (as the error message suggests, offering either `{` or `$`):

```
$parts->{0};

$num = 0;
$parts->$num;
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is right

```
$i = 0;
$part->$i = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternative ways to accomplish this task:

```php
<?php
// creating dummy object
$obj = (object)array(1=>'test1', 3=>'test3');
// cast obj to array
$arr = (array)$obj;

// access element at position `1` direcly
var_dump($arr[1]);

// rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element
$firstEl = reset($arr);
var_dump($firstEl);

// get the first key of an array w/o reset 
var_dump($arr[array_key_first($arr)]);

// if case your keys are only numbers
var_dump($arr);
$arr['test'] = 'index 2'; // this will be set to index 2
$restedKeys = array_values($arr);
echo $restedKeys[0] . PHP_EOL; // prints 'test1'
var_dump($restedKeys);
```

where you can use a variable instead of `1` or `0`, if needed within squre brackets `[$index]`.

[reset php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

[array_key_first php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first)

[Sandbox Example](https://onlinephp.io/c/a5e9e)